# Problems moving magento2 from shared cpanel to dedicated Centos 6 LAMP server

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-7, apache2, centos

I am having some problems with moving my magento 2.1.3 site from a shared cpanel server to a dedicated Centos 6.8 server with PHP 7.0.14, MySQL 5.6 & Apache 2.2

Here's what I did: I basically compressed all of the files in my public_html folder and exported my database SQL file.

Then uploaded the compressed folder to my /var/www/html folder on the dedicated server. Then imported my SQL file to the new database.

All seems to have gone ok but the site isn't loading properly. All that will load is the homepage with no styles or javascript. If I click on another page such as "products" for example, I get a 404 file not found error.

I have followed all instructions to set the users and permissions in the magento2 documentation, made sure mod_rewrite was enabled and then upgrade, compile, static:deploy, reindex and cache flush.

But nothing is having an effect. You can see the site here: http://www.invest-in-bullion.com

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I hadn't configured my httpd.conf file correctly. And all of the information I could find was telling me this is the problem but what I was doing was adding the below code to the file while there was already a `<Directory "var/www/html">` section that I just needed to edit.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>
```